# Smack (and XMPP) ability to perform batch search and add to roster operations?

Tags: search, batch-file, xmpp, openfire, smack

In general, does XMPP (and in particular the Smack library and the OpenFire server) support batch search and batch add to roster operations?
Cross-posted here: http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/43615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  One item at a time.  This is clarified in section [2.1.5 RFC 3921bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-xmpp-3921bis-20#section-2.1.5), which was recently approved:

> The <query/> element MUST contain one
> and only one <item/> element.